# Ubuntu 17.04 & natural scrolling

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.04, gnome-flashback

In Ubuntu 16.10 and earlier natural scroll settings for touchpad were separatefor mouse and touchpad. Since 17.04 there is only one settings so I can't set it differently for diffrent input devices.

Comment: You can set it separately in `libinput` that is default in 17.04.

Answer (score 1):

using the gsettings command line api, you should be able to access both
i.e. these command line commands will get the current values

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll
```

This returns `false` for me.
for touchpad

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll
```

Then to change, change the `get` argument to `set` and pass a value on the end, e.g.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
            ^^^                                                       ^^^^
```

and obviously repeat the process for the mouse if you want to change that as well.

Comment: The user asked about natural scroll settings, not speed. Do you have an answer for that?

Comment: Doesn't work. They are set diffrent for both devices, but none of them has natural-scroll: `kamil@galactica:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll` gets 
true
`kamil@galactica:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll` 
gets false

Comment: @Kamil do you want natural scroll on or off? you will have to use the second command and **set** the value you want

Comment: I wan't it on for touchpad and off for mouse. It is set like this, but it doesn't work.